# Ошибки при установке Yeoman, Grunt и Bower

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, npm

При установке Yeoman, Grunt и Bower на Ubuntu выдает данный список ошибок:

> npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>   /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
>   npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash'
>   File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash
>   Move it away, and try again.
>   npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-41-generic
>   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "bower"
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/dimapolishuk
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash
>   npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash/isMap.js
>   npm ERR! fstream_type File
>   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
>   npm ERR! code EEXIST
>   npm ERR! errno 47
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
>   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/lodash/array/zipWith.js'
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! or email it to:
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-41-generic
>   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "bower"
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/dimapolishuk
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/lodash/array/zipWith.js
>   npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/lodash/array/zipWith.js
>   npm ERR! fstream_type File
>   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno 34
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
>   npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/tabtab/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules/spawn-sync/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream'
>   npm ERR! error rolling back yo@1.8.4 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/tabtab/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules/spawn-sync/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream']
>   npm ERR! error rolling back errno: 53,
>   npm ERR! error rolling back code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
>   npm ERR! error rolling back path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/tabtab/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules/spawn-sync/node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream' }
>   npm ERR! weird error 1
>
> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/tabtab/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules/spawn-sync
>   node postinstall
>
> npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>   /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
>
> npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.lite.js'
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! or email it to:
>   npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-41-generic
>   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "bower"
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/dimapolishuk
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.lite.js
>   npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.lite.js
>   npm ERR! fstream_type File
>   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno 34
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
>   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-doctor/node_modules/twig/docs/twig.html'
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! or email it to:
>   npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-41-generic
>   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "bower"
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/dimapolishuk
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-doctor/node_modules/twig/docs/twig.html
>   npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-doctor/node_modules/twig/docs/twig.html
>   npm ERR! fstream_type File
>   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno 34
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
>   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
>   /usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>   npm ERR! /home/dimapolishuk/npm-debug.log
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0

Как их исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>   /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

Обновите node js

> npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash'
>   File exists:
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash
>   Move it away, and try again.

Файл существует в директории /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash

а надо по другому, так что перетащите lodash сюда
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/lodash